# Vue and DaisyUI dropdown links not calling scroll function

Tags: vue.js, daisyui

I have a list of links that are either part of the navbar when the screen is large or part of a dropdown when the screen is small. The function each link calls scrolls to the respective element. The scrolling works on the links in the expanded navbar but do not scroll when clicked from the dropdown. I am not sure what is not triggering correctly.

```html
<script setup>
 import {ref} from 'vue';
 function getImageUrl(name, ext) {
     return new URL(`../assets/${name}.jpg`, import.meta.url).href
 }
 // Scroll to the target element when a link is clicked
 function scrollToComponent(componentId) {
     const element = document.getElementById(componentId);
     if (element) {
         element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
     } else {
    console.warn(`Element with ID ${componentId} not found`);
  }
 }
</script>

<template>
    <div class="navbar bg-base-300 rounded">
        <div class="navbar-start">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="btn btn-ghost lg:hidden">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h8m-8 6h16" /></svg>
                </div>
                <ul class="menu menu-sm dropdown-content mt-3 z-[1] p-2 shadow bg-base-300 rounded-box w-52">
                    <li><a @click="scrollToComponent('home')">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a @click="scrollToComponent('about')">About</a></li>
                    <li><a @click="scrollToComponent('projects')">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a @click="scrollToComponent('resume')">Resume</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div tabindex="0" class="hidden lg:avatar">
                <div class="w-10 mask mask-squircle">
                    <img :src="getImageUrl('profile','jpg')" alt="Tailwind CSS Navbar component" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="ml-2 hidden lg:btn lg:btn-ghost lg:text-xl">Cade Lueker</a>
        </div>
        <div class="lg:hidden navbar-end">
            <a class="lm-2 btn btn-ghost text-xl">Cade Lueker</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-end hidden lg:flex">
            <ul class="menu menu-horizontal px-1">
                <li><a @click="scrollToComponent('home')">Home</a></li>
                <li><a @click="scrollToComponent('about')">About</a></li>
                <li><a @click="scrollToComponent('projects')">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a @click="scrollToComponent('resume')">Resume</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```